# C++: converting wstring to double

Tags: c++, double, wstring

Before converting `wstring` to `double` - how to validate it with regex? Java no problem, but C++ raising questions.. :)

Comment: Why "before"? Why not just convert and see if it works?

Comment: In Java I can catch an exception or use `"someString".matches(some regex)`, but how to do it in C++?

Comment: Try to convert the string and see if it works!

Comment: Ahh, so if it not - error will be returned?

Comment: You might want to have a look at Boost.Lexical_Cast: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast.html

Comment: Correct. That's how *any* kind of parsing works. You have to try before you know whether you'll succeed.

Comment: Putting aside if this is a good idea or not, you should probably start by reading about C++ regexes and then asking a specific question if you have trouble with it. Right now you haven't defined any problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you have a `string` and you want to know if it is a `double` or not. The following code does not use regular expressions. Instead it initializes a `stringstream` and reads a double from it. If the string starts with something non-numeric, then `ss.fail()` will be set. If it starts with a number, but does not read the whole string, then there's something non-numeric at the end of the string. So if everything went well and the string is really only a number, then `ss.eof() && !ss.fail()` will be `true`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    std::stringstream ss("123.456");
    double mydouble;
    ss >> mydouble;

    if (ss.eof() && !ss.fail())
        std::cout << "yay, success: " << mydouble << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "that was not a double." << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

There's also `std::wstringstream` if you need to convert wide character strings.

You might also want to have a look at the boost libraries, especially at [Boost.Lexical_Cast](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast.html). 
With this library you could do the following:

```
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    try
    {
        double mydouble = boost::lexical_cast<double>("123.456");
        std::cout << "yay, success: " << mydouble << std::endl;
    }
    catch(const boost::bad_lexical_cast &)
    {
        std::cout << "that was not a double." << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, and if I have only `wstring` - how to do that right?

Comment: Edited my post a few seconds ago. There's also `std::wstringstream` if you need to work with wide character strings.

Answer (score 0):

Or maybe it is simpler to do that this way:

```
std::wstring strKeyValue = "147.sd44";
double value = (double) _wtof(strKeyValue.c_str());
```

And if `strKeyValue==0` then it means it's not double.

Comment: You probably mean, that if `value=0`, then it's not a `double`. But what if `strKeyValue="0.00"`?

Comment: Yes, but in my situation 0 - it is already bad result. I'm trying to get Java version from Windows registry. But anyway - I liked the solution with `stringstream`.